# Arm(android) c++ https proxy

Tags: android, c++, proxy, android-ndk

I have a HTTP and HTTPs proxy for Linux and Android.
I have various Android devices - Nexus 5 (CPU 2260, RAM 2Gb), Nexus 7(CPU 1200, RAM 1Gb) and a Nexus 9(CPU 2300 , RAM 2Gb).

The issue is that while the HTTP proxy works well on all devices, the Nexus 7 can't open heavy pages when using the HTTPs proxy.

I am assuming that this is caused by RAM and/or CPU shortage. Can I change something in the code below to fix that? I need my proxy to work on weak devices.

My code :

When I connected website I call :

```
void connection::inform_browser_ok() {

    const std::string answer = "HTTP/1.1 200 Connection  established\r\n\r\n";
    ba::async_write(bsocket_, ba::buffer(answer),
                boost::bind(&connection::browser_read_ssl,
                shared_from_this(),
                ba::placeholders::error,
                ba::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
}
```

then I charge callbacks :

```
void connection::browser_read_ssl(const bs::error_code& err, size_t len) {

    if(!err) {
        async_read(bsocket_, ba::buffer(bbuffer), ba::transfer_at_least(1),
                           boost::bind(&connection::server_write_ssl,
                                       shared_from_this(),
                                       ba::placeholders::error,
                                       ba::placeholders::bytes_transferred));

    }else {
        shutdown();
    }
}


void connection::browser_write_ssl(const bs::error_code& err, size_t len) {

    if(!err) {
        ba::async_write(bsocket_, ba::buffer(sbuffer, len),
                        boost::bind(&connection::browser_read_ssl,
                        shared_from_this(),
                        ba::placeholders::error,
                        ba::placeholders::bytes_transferred));

    async_read(ssocket_, ba::buffer(sbuffer), ba::transfer_at_least(1),
                       boost::bind(&connection::browser_write_ssl,
                       shared_from_this(),
                       ba::placeholders::error,
                       ba::placeholders::bytes_transferred));

    }else {
        shutdown();
    }
}


void connection::server_read_ssl(const bs::error_code& err, size_t len) {

    if(!err) {

        async_read(ssocket_, ba::buffer(sbuffer), ba::transfer_at_least(1),
                       boost::bind(&connection::browser_write_ssl,
                       shared_from_this(),
                       ba::placeholders::error,
                       ba::placeholders::bytes_transferred));

    }else {
         shutdown();
     }
 }


void connection::server_write_ssl(const bs::error_code& err, size_t len) {

    if(!err) {
        ba::async_write(ssocket_, ba::buffer(bbuffer, len),
            boost::bind(&connection::server_read_ssl, shared_from_this(),
            ba::placeholders::error,
            ba::placeholders::bytes_transferred));

    async_read(bsocket_, ba::buffer(bbuffer), ba::transfer_at_least(1),
               boost::bind(&connection::server_write_ssl,
               shared_from_this(),
               ba::placeholders::error,
               ba::placeholders::bytes_transferred));

    }else {
        shutdown();
    }

}
```

So can someone tell me - what is wrong? How can my code be fixed?

UPDATE 1.
I cannot repeat previous error where page was not loaded at all - now I get something like

1)"This site can't provide a secure connection" - I guess in  server_read_ssl I lost some data... or united 2 different buffers..

2)Poor-looking page - (as I can guess - CSS was not loaded).

Comment: Please add more details regarding what _"cannot be opened"_ means. Also, what have you done in terms of debugging/logging this problem to find out more about _why_ it occurs?

Comment: Sorry for my  question's poor description. I cannot repeat  previous error where page was not loaded at all - now I get something like "This site can't provide a secure connection" or  poor-looking page - (as I can guess - CSS was not loaded).